# How to save data to ListBox on button click event mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, icommand

I  have to enter some data in text-boxes and then have to click save button, The data i have written must save in the List-box below which has same column as all text boxes.
I am not able to understand how to save data using ICommand and pass it to ListBox such that as i save it the same instant it get displayed in Listbox.

Some thing like this http://prntscr.com/9nm6u8

But i am not able to understand how to bind the data such that when i put textboxes and then click save must update this grid by that data **all using MVVM only**.

My try to do is (which obiously does nothign thats why i am here for help):

My full code is:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int userId;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string city;
        private string state;
        private string country;

        public int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return userId;
            }
            set
            {
                userId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
            }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return city;
            }
            set
            {
                city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return country;
            }
            set
            {
                country = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Country");
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class UserViewModel
    {
        private IList<User> _UsersList;
        public UserViewModel()
        {
            _UsersList = new List<User>
            {
               // new User{UserId = 1,FirstName="sam",LastName="Disouza",City="lonero",State="Depra",Country="USA"},
            };
        }
        /* 
         *
          public UserViewModel(User usr)
        {
            _UsersList = new List<User>
            {
                new User{UserId = usr.UserId,FirstName=usr.FirstName,LastName=usr.LastName,City=usr.City,State=usr.State,Country=usr.Country},
            };
        }
         */
        public IList<User> Users
        {
            get { return _UsersList; }
            set { _UsersList = value; }
        }
        private ICommand mUpdater;
        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (mUpdater == null)
                    mUpdater = new Updater();
                return mUpdater;
            }
            set
            {
                mUpdater = value;
            }
        }
        private class Updater : ICommand
        {
            #region ICommand Members
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="UserId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserId}"  Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.UserId}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,62,0,0" Name="txtLastName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.LastName}" />
        <Label Content="UserId" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
        <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,50,0,0" Name="btnSave" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
                Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommad}"  />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,143,0,0" x:Name="txtCity" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="Country" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,141,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,88,0,0" x:Name="txtCountry" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Country, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="City" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,86,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,115,0,0" x:Name="txtSTate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.State, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="State" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,113,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new UserViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**Could some one please help me in accomplishing my target ?**

Comment: Your `UserViewModel` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. I implement that in a common `ViewModelBase` class that all viewmodel classes inherit from. `Users` should be `ObservableCollection<User>`. Have a property User EditUser which is never null -- bind the textboxes to its properties. In the save command, the listview will add EditUser to Users and create a new empty EditUser. To edit an existing user, end user doubleclicks on listview and the doubleclicked item is assigned to EditUser.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `RelayCommand` to bind your command. Also, you need to add a command parameter if you want to send data to your command.

See this code snippet http://snipplr.com/view/13642/ import the class and the implementation is below

2) There's a typo in your command binding `SaveCommad` should be `SaveCommand`

Add CommandParameter{Binding} this will send your viewmodel as context in your view button:

```
<Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,50,0,0" Name="btnSave" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
            Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommad}",CommandParameter{Binding}  />
```

ViewModel:

```
RelayCommand _saveCommand;    
public ICommand SaveCommand    
{    
   get    
   {    
      if (_saveCommand== null)    
      {    
        _saveCommand= new RelayCommand(p => this.SaveCommand((object)p),    
        p => this.CanSaveCommand(p) ); // you can set it to true for testing purpose or bind it to a property IsValid if u want to disable the button   
      }    
    return _saveCommand;    
   }

}

private void SaveCommand(object vm)
{
     //Actual implementation to insert into list.
}
private bool CanSaveCommand(object vm)
{
    return true;
}

YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChange // to enable notification to your view
private User _currentUser;
public User CurrentUser {get return _currentUser;} set{_currentUser = value; NotifyPropertyChange("CurrentUser")

//Or Simply Insert all property of user to your viewmodel so your input have acces to content
private string _name;
public string Name {get return _name;} set{_name = value; NotifyPropertyChange("Name")
```

In your XAML for option 1:

```
Text={Binding CurrentUser.Name,Mode="TwoWay",UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

In your XAML for option 2:

```
Text={Binding Name,Mode="TwoWay",UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Comment: Thanks and what about the binding of textBoxes in which i enter the texts to be saved, Is the way i done the binding correct ? ( <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.UserId}" />)

Comment: And why you have kept commandParameter empty (CommandParameter{Binding} ) ?

Comment: For the command parameter {binding} is the datacontext of actual windows ( so it is ur viewmodel )

For the textbox, u have to either add a property to your viewmodel
public User CurrentUser{get return _user;} set{_user = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(CurrentUser)}
In your xaml
Text="{binding CurrentUser.Name}"

Or simply add all property inside your view model of user class
Public string Name {get return _name;} set{_name = value; NotifyPropertyChange("Name");

And in your xaml Text={Binding Name,Mode="TwoWay" UpdateOnSourceUpdate="PropertyChange" // not sure if its the correct property